# Fredholm alternative theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm studying in a PDE's course and we have recently used Fredholm alternative theorem as a tool in order to prove the existence and the uniqueness of the solution of a particular problem. We have seen that using the maximum principle it is possible to prove the uniqueness of the solution (assuming that it exists). What I don't get is: why we have uniqueness iff we have the existence?

Comment: Answering why is not so easy. Can you easily tell me why the rows of a square matrix are linearly-independent iff the columns are linearly-independent? The Fredholmn alternative implies this. Or, more generally, can you easily explain why the row rank of a square matrix is the same as the column rank?

Answer (score 3):

Fredholm alternative: If $K : X \to X$ is a compact operator, $I + K : X \to X$ is surjective iff it is injective.

In other words,
$$(I + X) \, x = 0$$
has only the trivial solution $x = 0$, iff
$$(I + X) \, x = b$$
is solvable for every $b$.

That is, uniqueness yields existence (and vice versa).